# Is there a word for left-to-right and top-to-bottom?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I was learning about web design, and I remember similar things from art classes, people said that the eye sees things the most on a page which are in a line from the top-left to bottom-right corners.

Is there a word or phrase for that line? I've heard "order of the occident" to refer to the order western text is written, but that's not really the same thing.

EDIT: 
So I tried [this question on UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25759), and there is a design term for it: "Gutenberg Diagram", sometimes called a "Gutenberg Diagonal". There doesn't seem to be a single non-industry word for the pattern, however.

Comment: This might be a more appropriate question for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you mean diagonal?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a specific word for what you're describing. It's simply called "left-to-right, top-to-bottom". You could borrow a foreign term like [*yokogaki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system#Direction_of_writing) but few would understand you without context. We don't have single words to describe every directional type of script, though there are some interesting ones (e.g. scripts written [*boustrophedonically*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon)).

Comment: A similar discussion took place on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_talk:TextDir).

Comment: I was looking for something like boustrophedon, but it seems like there isn't one for this. That strikes me as odd, since its used in so many different areas.

Comment: @Matt, no, since diagonal could mean any diagonal and this is a particular one.

Comment: Good point. Could check out uxSE as well.

Comment: Since there aren't any languages that are written bottom-to-top, then left-to-right or right-to-left will do adequately when describing writing. This might come up in other areas like industrial control, though (some systems covering a rectangular area will proceed horizontally in alternating directions like a ploughman, while others will return to the left for each horizontal line and make a series of Z shapes or zigzags/sawtooth patterns). Something like left-to-right zigzag will describe this motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [scientific article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3884523), the term is

> directional preferences in perception of visual stimuli.

This [article](http://tamu.academia.edu/JyotsnaVaid/Papers/420853/Stroke_Direction_Asymmetry_In_Figure_Drawing_Influence_of_Handedness_and_Reading_Writing_Habits) refers to

> stroke direction asymmetry

It is notable that there are different directional patterns associated with different cultures and their writing systems.

I am not aware of a term in common parlance that indicates the particular directional pattern you mention or the broader category of directional preferences.

Comment: +1 What do folks on uxSE have to say on this?

Answer (score 0):

I call it *left-to-right then top-to-bottom, normal English reading order* in my technical documentation.

Comment: This would benefit from a source or citation.  Is there a single word as per the question?

Answer (score 0):

Always thought it was T(op)L(eft)-D(own)R(right) but some people seem to have misappropriated that for other uses

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).